# Comparing doubles

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that consists of a while loop that reads two doubles and prints them. The program also prints what the larger number is and what the smaller number is.

this is the code i have so far.

```
int main()
{

                                    // VARIABLE DECLARATIONS 

    double a;
    double b;

    while (a,b != '|')              //WHILE A & B DO NOT EQUAL '|'
    {
        cin >>a >>b;
        cout << a << b << "\n" ;


        if (a<b)                    //IF A<B: SMALLER VALUE IS A
        cout << "The smaller value is:" << a << endl 
             << "The larger value is:" << b << endl ;

        else if (b<a)               //ELSE IF B<A 
            cout << "The smaller value is:" << b << endl 
                 << "The larger value is:" << a << endl ;
        else if (b==a)
            cout << "The two numbers you entered are equal." << "\n" ;

    }
}
```

The next step is having the program write out "the numbers are almost equal" if the two numbers differ by less than 1.0/10000000. How would I do this?

Comment: Smells homework, so please add the tag *homework* if that's the case.

Comment: Funny how far that smell can travel...

Comment: @user484955: Do you really know what `while (a,b != '|')` means ?

Comment: go easy on me i'm just starting out. I'm assuming the while condition is wrong because I declared a and b as doubles and '|' is not a double. Is that the case?

Comment: You need to do `while (a != '|' && b != '|')`. What you have uses the comma operator, which evaluates `a`, then evaluates `b != '|'`, resulting in `b != '|'`. In other words, you have `while (b != '|')`, discarding `a`. Now, why you're comparing it to that, I still don't know.

Comment: @GMan: I'd point out more clearly that comparing a double to a char doesn't make sense at all. @Capkutay: if you want to use a "magic character" to terminate the `while`, you should acquire a string, check if it's the "magic character" and then convert it to a double with an `istringstream`. Otherwise, just tell to the user that any non-number will end the cycle, acquire doubles and check for stream failure: when the `fail()` bit is set, the input couldn't be converted to double, so you can use that as a condition.

Comment: I'm comparing it to that because the program must terminate when the user enters '|'. thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Capkutay: But if the user enters `'|'`, the `operator>>(std::istream&, double&`) will fail, because | is not a valid double. You have to read a string, and convert to a double, instead.

Comment: @billy Just out of curiosity, is there any reason  _not_ to trust the ability of cout? I mean, atof is good and all, but that seems like a waste of a perfectly good operator, the function will still fail and cause issues using atof.

Comment: @jaked122: Mostly because 1. it is extremely slow, and 2. because the failure mode of "return a proxy object and set failbit" sucks, and 2a. debugging why your app just randomly stopped printing or reading data sucks too.

Answer (score 28):

Here is how I would test for equality, without a "fudge factor":

```
if (
    // Test 1: Very cheap, but can result in false negatives
    a==b || 
    // Test 2: More expensive, but comprehensive
    std::abs(a-b)<std::abs(std::min(a,b))*std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
  std::cout << "The numbers are equal\n";
```

**Explanation**

The first test is a simple comparison. Of course we all know that comparing double precision values can result in them being deemed unequal, even when they are logically equivalent.

A double precision floating point value can hold the most significant fifteen digits of a number (actually [≈15.955](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) digits). Therefore, we want to call two values equal if (approximately) their first fifteen digits match. To phrase this another way, we want to call them equal if they are within one scaled epsilon of each other. This is exactly what the second test computes.

You can choose to add more leeway than a single scaled epsilon, due to more significant floating point errors creeping in as a result of iterative computation. To do this, add an error factor to the right hand side of the second test's comparison:

```
double error_factor=2.0;

if (a==b ||         
    std::abs(a-b)<std::abs(std::min(a,b))*std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()*
                  error_factor)
  std::cout << "The numbers are equal\n";
```

I cannot give you a fixed value for the `error_factor`, since it will depend on the amount of error that creeps into your computations. However, with some testing you should be able to find a reasonable value that suits your application. Do keep in mind that adding an (arbitrary) error factor based on speculation alone will put you right back into fudge factor territory.

**Summary**

You can wrap the following test into a(n inline) function:

```
inline bool logically_equal(double a, double b, double error_factor=1.0)
{
  return a==b || 
    std::abs(a-b)<std::abs(std::min(a,b))*std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()*
                  error_factor;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to replace the "/1.e-15" to "/1.e15" otherwise the RHS of the comparison is huge.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: can you please explain what's the reasoning behind `std::abs(a-b)<std::min(a,b)/1.e15`?

Comment: @Mihai, it has to do with the maximum number of whole digits that a double can represent, namely fifteen. So, if the absolute value of the result of subtraction has less than the smallest value that a subtraction can produce due to imprecise representation, call the original numbers not equal.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: thank you for taking time to write the clarification.

Comment: Great solution. This was the first I found that got to the heart of the problem and provided a comprehensive solution. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

`std::abs(a - b) < 0.000001`

Of course, replace the constant with whatever you consider "almost".

Comment: Also, note that the "error" will scale up with the size of a and b.

Comment: @Fredrik: True, but the OP specified "two numbers differ by less than SOMECONSTANT". Of course, you could cobble together something checking if the exponents on the values were the same, and then using a similar constant on the mantissas only.

Comment: @Billy ONeil: Yes, I just wanted to add it as an extra piece of information. I see way too much code written by people without basic understanding of why the "less than 1e-10" is not always working to keep quiet about it :-). I didn't expect you to alter your answer, I just thought it was overkill to write a more complete one myself. Comparisons is just one side of the problem, you will see another side when adding, multiplying etc as well. Maybe incorrectly, I assumed the OP didn't have that knowledge/experience yet.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, that's why you got +1 from me for use of `std::numeric_limits` :P

Answer (score 4):

Just test if they differ by less than that amount :)

```
if ( std::abs(a - b) < 1.0 / 10000000 )
  cout << "The numbers are almost equal.\n";
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error that reads "Call of overloaded 'abs(double)' is ambiguous"

Comment: Capkutay: Did you #include `<cmath>` ? That's required for `std::abs` to work. It's also possible you've got a `using namespace std;` somewhere, which is bad practice, and could cause a conflict between `std::abs` and `abs` in the global namespace. (`abs` is allowed, but not required, to be put in the global namespace, because it is inherited from C) Fix that by removing the `using namespace std;` and qualifying your calls to the standard library as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (a * 1.0000001 > b  &&  a < b*1.0000001)
```

You can add an error value (your 1.0 / 10000000.0 ) but it is generally better to use a multiplier, so the comparison is to the same level of accuracy.

Comment: The other answers are going for the absolute error value. This might even be quicker, but is only accurate when you know the order of magnitude of the two values.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following article: [new link](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) 
 (obsolete link->[Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm))

Answer (score 1):

```
abs(a - b) < 1.0 / 10000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the test to scale with a and b, you could try testing abs(a/b-1) < e, where e is your favorite tiny number, like 0.001.  But this condition is actually asymmetrical in a and b, so it can work out to say a is close to b, but b is not close to a.  That would be bad.  It's better to do abs(log(a/b)) < e, where e, again, is your favorite tiny number.  But the logarithms present extra computation, not to mention terrifying undergraduates everywhere.

Comment: 1. "favorite tiny number` should probably be `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`, 2. Log is probably not the best way to handle this anyway. If you want a comparison similar to this, you should be checking the sign and exponent for equality and then compare the significands allowing for some error value. (Use `frexp` to do that -- it should perform much better than `log` or `log10`)

Comment: One of the better answers in that it compares by relative to a and b, however it is better to multiply than divide. For one b might be zero.
abs(a-b) < abs(epsilon*b) (or epsilon*(a+b)/2 for symmetry)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also reading the book, since we didn't get to std::abs, i did something like that:

```
int main()
{
double i1,i2;
while(cin>> i1 >> i2){

if (i1<i2) {
        if ((i2-i1)<=0.0000001)  cout << "Almost equal!"<<endl;
        else  cout << "the smaller value is: "<< i1 <<  " the larger value is: " << i2 <<endl;
}
if (i1>i2) {
        if ((i1-i2)<=0.0000001)  cout << "Almost equal!"<<endl;
        else  cout << "the smaller value is: "<< i2 <<  " the larger value is: " << i1 <<endl;
}


else if (i1==i2) cout << "the value : "<< i1 <<  " And the value : " << i2 << "  are equal!"<<endl;

}
}
```