# ULP comparison code

Tags: c++, floating-point, bitwise-operators

The following code snippet is scattered all over the web and seems to be used in multiple different projects with very little changes:

```
union Float_t {
    Float_t(float num = 0.0f) : f(num) {}
    // Portable extraction of components.
    bool Negative()    const { return (i >> 31) != 0; }
    int  RawMantissa() const { return i & ((1 << 23) - 1); }
    int  RawExponent() const { return (i >> 23) & 0xFF; }

    int i;
    float f;
};

inline bool AlmostEqualUlpsAndAbs(float A, float B, float maxDiff, int maxUlpsDiff)
{
    // Check if the numbers are really close -- needed
    // when comparing numbers near zero.
    float absDiff = std::fabs(A - B);
    if (absDiff <= maxDiff)
        return true;

    Float_t uA(A);
    Float_t uB(B);

    // Different signs means they do not match.
    if (uA.Negative() != uB.Negative())
        return false;

    // Find the difference in ULPs.
    return (std::abs(uA.i - uB.i) <= maxUlpsDiff);
}
```

See, for example [here](https://xp-dev.com/trac/dvd-fmwk/browser/divide-framework/trunk/Source%20Code/Hardware/Platform/Headers/PlatformDefines.h?rev=318) or [here](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/GMT/gmt-5.2.1-src.tar.gz/gmt-5.2.1/src/common_math.c) or [here](https://github.com/narfblock/narfblock/blob/master/src/narf/math/floats.cpp).

However, I don't understand what is going on here. To my (maybe naive) understanding, the floating-point member variable `f` is initialized in the constructor, but the integer member `i` is not.

I'm not terribly familiar with the binary operators that are used here, but I fail to understand how accesses of `uA.i` and `uB.i` produce anything but random numbers, given that no line in the code actually connects the values of `f` and `i` in any meaningful way.

If somebody could enlighten my on why (and how) exactly this code produces the desired result, I would be very delighted!

Comment: looks like some non portable bit trickery is going on.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, I'll have to rewrite and cleanup this code, so I'd like to understand what exactly is going on first :-)

Comment: @carsten, FYI, the code originates from Bruce Dawson's [blog series on floating point](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). A full explanation is given over there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of Undefined Behaviour are being exploited here. First assumption is that fields of union can be accessed in place of each other, which is, in itself, UB. Furthermore, coder assumes that: `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)`, that floats have a given length of mantissa and exponent, that all union members are aligned to zero, that the binary representation of float coincides with the binary representation with int in a very specific way. In short, this will work as long as you're on x86, have specific int and float types and you say a prayer at every sunrise and sunset.

What you probably didn't note is that this is a union, therefore `int i` and `float f` is usually aligned in a specific manner in a common memory array by most compilers. This is, in general, still UB and you can't even safely assume that the same physical bits of memory will be used without restricting yourself to a specific compiler *and* a specific architecture. All that's guaranteed is, the address of both members will be the same (but there might be alignment and/or typedness issues). Assuming that your compiler uses the same physical bits (which is by no means guaranteed by standard) and they both start at offset 0 and have the same size, then `i` will represent the binary storage format of `f`.. as long as *nothing* changes in your architecture. Word of advice? Do not use it until you don't have to. Stick to floating point operations for `AlmostEquals()`, you can implement it like that. It's the very final pass of optimization when we consider these specialities and we usually do it in a separate branch, you shouldn't plan your code around it.

Comment: I understand that I best exchange this piece of code by something like this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010240/comparing-doubles), but I need to keep interface compatibility, so I would need to understand what the arguments do exactly, e.g. how to translate `maxUlpsDiff` to something portable. Would you care to comment on that?

Comment: Worse - type-punning i.e. reading one type 'as though it were' a different type simply is not allowed in C++. This includes use of `union` to attempt this. In C, you can use a `union` for this. In C++, **it's pure UB**. So even if the types' bit representations were guaranteed, that wouldn't save this code. It's not savable. It might work on most compilers, which can't be bothered to make it mow your lawn instead, but it's a nonportable hack and therefore should be consigned directly to `/dev/null`.

Comment: You're welcome. I've not voted but would +1 if you make that caveat doubly clear in your 2nd paragraph too :P I worry that someone, somewhere will manage not to make the connection otherwise. To restate: "`i` will represent the binary storage format of `f`" might be an obvious happenstance of efficient compiler implementation, but it is not required whatsoever. As an example, personally I would say something like 'as evidenced by the unfortunate prevalence of code like this, it is very possible in non-capricious compilers, but UB and hence not guaranteed per the Standard, that...'

Comment: @underscore_d: everything to have good answers around in stackoverflow :). BTW, I was thinking of counter-examples and possible architectures... Is it guaranteed that a union is allocated as a continuous range? If not, the compiler might allocate it as a memory address and a floating point register (or an int register and a fp registed). Do you think it's possible?

Comment: @lorro `union` members must have the same address, so they must have an address, so neither the `union` nor any of its members can be stored in a register. Here's a thread that neatly summarises what the Standard says about the address: https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/132946-address-union-members

Comment: @lorro But that made me wonder about optimisation. I guess _maybe_ if you only use 1 member, the compiler could optimise _as-if_ you declared 1 typed object, and if that supports going in a register, it _might_ be possible... but then you don't actually have a `union`. Then you think... What if we use both members but never take any address? Can't it be optimised under _as-if_? Well, no: a register can't have 2 types. But can the compiler allocate 2 registers and pretend they're at the same address? And the answer is...good question :S My gut says no, but not sure. Fancy opening a question? ;)

Comment: But I should clarify that I doubt such optimisations exist. After all, if you only wanted 1 variable, you'd declare thusly. If you wanted 2 but didn't care if they reused storage/had the same address, you'd declare them separately, not in a `union`. So I rather doubt that a compiler would either be allowed or at least bother trying to make such optimisations, just to do an unasked favour to users who went out of their way to write weird code that doesn't do what it declares it's going to do.

Comment: @underscore_d: Thanks for the doc, I've checked it. While you say that the same address is assigned, there are two possible tricks here: 1. what if you don't take the address?, 2. more importantly, what if memory is managed in a way that some addresses are considered 'register file', in which segment the binary representation of an int is on different bits as for a float (i.e., a gp and a fp register gets the same address *together*). Is there anything forbidding this? I'm actually interested because fp registers on x86 are quite fast & convenient if you don't move a lot from/to...

Comment: @lorro Yeah, I wondered about **1** in my comment. **2** refers to addresses, not registers, so I don't see the relevance? does any architecture expose its registers also as memory? anyway, if they had the same address and thus perform the `union`'s function of allowing differently typed recycling (_not_ reinterpretation) of storage, I don't see an issue... nor any difference from normal usage. Anyway, I'd recommend writing a question on all these ideas if you can formulate one. It interests me, but I'm all questioned out for the week, whereas it sounds like you have more energy and interest!

Comment: Lastly, and following from the above, I suggest changing `you can't even safely assume that the same memory will be used`. You **can** assume that because all members must have the same address. (I'm excluding _maybe possible_ optimisations that nix said requirement.) What you can't guarantee is that `union U { int i; float f; } u; u.i = 120; /* do things with i */ u.f = 45354.3; /* now the coder expects to see the bit representation of f */ std::cout << u.i << std::endl;` will work - because the optimiser is within its rights to ignore the write to `f` and just print `120`. Remember aliasing?

Comment: To rephrase: The same memory **will** be used... if any. What is **not** required is that the compiler take previous writes to a different member into account when reading another. It is well within its rights to produce code _as-if_ `i` above is a completely separate variable from `f` (which just _happens_ to live at the same address). Thus, the C++ Standard stipulates that _reading from a `union` member other than the one last written is UB_. This promotes optimisation and also avoids _many_ uncomfortable questions arising from C++'s notions of object lifetime, construction, destruction, etc

Comment: @underscore_d: I agree with that, but that's not exactly what I meant there. I meant typed memory and/or alignment issues. I've changed it, hope that's easier to understand now.